# Inside a CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout, how to set ScrollView or RecyclerView above an EditText that is fixed to bottom?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I need to use a RecyclerView inside a CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout. Below AppBarLayout, I have a RecyclerView. But, I would also like to fix a LinearLayout at the bottom of screen. The LinearLayout contains an EditText. When I scroll items in RecyclerView, they are superimposed with the EditText. I don't know how to set my RecyclerView items above LinearLayout or EditText.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

I put below an image of my screen

[image]

Here below my XML code

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout_channel_chat"
tools:context=".view.MyActivity">

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_channel_chat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0E66B9"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/my_menu"
    app:itemIconTint="#fff"
    app:itemHorizontalPadding="40dp"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextViewStyle"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/menu_item_padding"/>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/channel_chat_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar_channel_chat">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_theme_channel_chat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_theme_channel_chat"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/img_theme_channel_chat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:text="@string/channel_chat_txt"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/text_view_border"
                    />

                <View
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_theme_channel_chat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_channel_chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_channel_chat"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            app:stackFromEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/channel_chat_layout"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_preview_channel_chat"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/input_background">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_send_channel_chat"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/send_btn_rounded"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
                    />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_channel_chat"
                    android:hint="Votre message ..."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="17dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/channel_chat_floating_action_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
            fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
            fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
            fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
            fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
            fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
            fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
            fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
            fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
            fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
            fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
            fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
            fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
            fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
            fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
            fab:menu_labels_padding="4dp"
            fab:menu_labels_position="left"
            fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
            fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
            fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
            fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
            fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
            fab:menu_openDirection="up"
            fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
            fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
            fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
            fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
            fab:menu_showShadow="true">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_parametre_channel_chat_floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
                fab:fab_label="Paramètres"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_camera_channel_chat_floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_photo_camera_24"
                fab:fab_label="Camera"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_pick_image_channel_chat_floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"
                fab:fab_label="Gallerie"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />

        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to wrap the `LinearLayout` and `RecyclerView` **inside** a `NestedScrollView` and use `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on the NestedScrollView.

Also, remove the ScrollView that is wrapping your LinearLayout and RecyclerView.

Comment: OK, let's try right now and I'll give you feedback. Thank's !

Comment: When I wrap Recyclerview and LinearLayout inside a NestedScrollView and set **app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"** on NestedScrollView , LinearLayout is placed bellow RecyclerView. But, we have to scroll until end to see the LinearLayout. So EditText is hidden until we scroll also. I would like to keep EditText visible without the need to srcoll.

Comment: I need more advice. I wrapped CoordinatorLayout and LinearLayout with EditText inside a RelativeLayout. Then I used **android:layout_above="@+id/channel_chat_layout"** on CoordinatorLayout to set it above LinearLayout. At last I used **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** on LinearLayout to fix it at bottom of screen. 
I looked for without succeed a good solution, even if I could fix EditText at bottom and keep RecyclerView below AppBarLayout but behind EditText, it would suit me. So that items in RecyclerView would seem to be behind EditText and not superimposed like in my picture.